# Is CryptoLocker part of the TeslaCrypt ransomware family?

Tags: malware, ransomware

I'm reading a [Microsoft report](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/portal/mmpc/shared/ransomware.aspx#prevalent) examining the most prevalent ransomware families as of recent.

On the news, I've heard of CryptoLocker, CryptoWall and TeslaCrypt, but I don't see any of them mentioned by name. Only the "family" is marked there.

What is the *family* > *brand* correspondence here?

BTW, here's an [McAfee article](https://blogs.mcafee.com/mcafee-labs/teslacrypt-joins-ransomware-field/) on TeslaCrypt, stating that it looks like CryptoLocker, without actually being the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CryptoLocker was [taken down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoLocker) in 2014. Some copycat ransomware developers have chosen to imitate it, but the original CryptoLocker is gone. TeslaCrypt, CryptoWall etc. are all different strains of ransomware.

However, because of the aforementioned copying of CryptoLocker's name and because it was the first ransomware to be widely succesfull, some media continue to refer to all ransomware as "CryptoLocker" even though the different ransomware strains aren't based off its code.

**Edit:** after comparing [the description of TesCrypt given by Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?Name=Win32%2FTescrypt) to the [Bleeping Computer TeslaCrypt ransomware FAQ & removal guide](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/teslacrypt-alphacrypt-ransomware-information) I can confirm that TesCrypt = TeslaCrypt. The same goes for Crowti; Microsoft [lists](https://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?Name=Win32%2FCrowti) *Cryptowall* as an alternate name.
(I hate it that many AV vendors come up with different names for the same malware, it makes life more difficult for no good reason.)

Comment: @Agostino see the update to my post.